# Custom bundle migrations fail at first install because they run before OroCommerce's installers

Tags: orocommerce

I created a custom bundle in which I have a few migrations, among them is one that adds a field to the `Product` entity, making the `oro_product` table a dependency for this migration to run.

The problem is that when I run the `oro:install` command, it runs the migrations, but fails at the beginning because it runs my custom bundle's migrations *first*, and that won't work because the `oro_product` table doesn't exist at this point in time.

Is there a way to control in which order the migrations are executed, or is there something else to do to avoid this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load the schema migration later, you can set the higher bundle priority in the `<BundleDirectory>/Resources/config/oro/bundles.yml` file. E.g.:

```yaml
bundles:
    - { name: Acme\Bundle\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle, priority: 1000 }
```